# Center flex items while positioning one in corner

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've started to experiment with flexbox lately, but still can't wrap my head around some things.

I am trying to create a simple layout with three flex items (children). The container is set to `flex-direction: column` and all the flex items are centered horizontally and vertically.

**I would like one of the flex items to be positioned at the top left corner.**
Basically like I am using `position: absolute` with `top: 30px; left: 30px;`.

I know that `align-self` is used to override styles for each flex item, but I can't get it to work.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49eghxna/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `pseudo` element and `flex` & `order` rules: http://jsfiddle.net/49eghxna/2/

```css
.flex-container {
    max-width:80%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height:600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1E5655
}
.flex-container:before, .flex-container:after {
    content:'';
    flex:1;/* will use and share all space avalaible if no values set to others */
}
.flex-container:before {
    order:2
}
.flex-container:after {
    order:5
}
.flex-item {
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #eee;
    order:3;
}
.flex-item:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #FFD454;
    order:4
}
.flex-item:nth-of-type(1) {
    align-self: flex-start;
    order:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clever, thanks a lot. I've also found this, although it user row instead of column for direction, second example on the page (http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Comment: @madebym well, you asked about flex ;) , notice that the display table works from IE8

Answer (score 2):

You can position a flex item in a corner, while centering sibling flex items, with [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) and an invisible flex item.

**HTML** (add one flex item)

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div><!-- invisible flex item for balance -->
</div>
```

**CSS** (relevant sections)

```
.flex-item:nth-of-type(1) { margin-bottom: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) { }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(3) { }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(4) { margin-top: auto; visibility: hidden; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/49eghxna/4/)

*NOTE: This centering and positioning solution will work when all flex items are equal height. If flex items vary in height (or width, when `flex-direction` is `row`), then true centering will be off and absolute positioning may be the better solution.*

For an absolute positioning method, and other centering and positioning options, see this answer:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)