# In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?

Tags: css, flexbox, language-lawyer

Consider the main axis and cross axis of a flex container:

[image: An illustration of the various directions and sizing terms as applied to a row flex container]
<sub>Source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)</sub>

To align flex items along the main axis there is one property:

- [`justify-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)

To align flex items along the cross axis there are three properties:

- [`align-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
- [`align-items`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
- [`align-self`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)

In the image above, the main axis is horizontal and the cross axis is vertical. These are the default directions of a flex container.

However, these directions can be easily interchanged with the [`flex-direction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-direction) property.

```
/* main axis is horizontal, cross axis is vertical */
flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row-reverse;

/* main axis is vertical, cross axis is horizontal */    
flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

(The cross axis is always perpendicular to the main axis.)

My point in describing how the axes' work is that there doesn't seem to be anything special about either direction. Main axis, cross axis, they're both equal in terms of importance and `flex-direction` makes it easy to switch back and forth.

*So why does the cross axis get two additional alignment properties?*

*Why are `align-content` and `align-items` consolidated into one property for the main axis?*

*Why does the main axis not get a `justify-self` property?*

---

Scenarios where these properties would be useful:

- placing a flex item in the corner of the flex container
  `#box3 { align-self: flex-end; justify-self: flex-end; }`
- making a group of flex items align-right (`justify-content: flex-end`) but have the first item align left (`justify-self: flex-start`)

*Consider a header section with a group of nav items and a logo. With `justify-self` the logo could be aligned left while the nav items stay far right, and the whole thing adjusts smoothly ("flexes") to different screen sizes.*

- in a row of three flex items, affix the middle item to the center of the container  (`justify-content: center`) and align the adjacent items to the container edges (`justify-self: flex-start` and `justify-self: flex-end`).

*Note that values `space-around` and `space-between` on
`justify-content` property  will not keep the middle item centered about the container if the adjacent items have different widths.*

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: springgreen;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.box3 {
  width: 200px;
}
#center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#center > span {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <span>TRUE CENTER</span>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>

<p>note that the middlebox will only be truly centered if adjacent boxes are equal width</p>
```

[jsFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/7an37m20/12/)

---

As of this writing, there is no mention of `justify-self` or `justify-items` in the [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

However, in the [CSS Box Alignment Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/), which is the W3C's unfinished proposal to establish a common set of alignment properties for use across all box models, there is this:

[image]
                                                                                                                                                   <sub>Source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-align/#overview)</sub>

You'll notice that `justify-self` and `justify-items` are being considered... *but not for flexbox*.

---

I'll end by reiterating the main question:

> Why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?

Comment: How would you expect `justify-self` to work for a flex item? Suppose you have items a,b,c,d with extra space to distribute around them, and the flex container has `justify-content: space-between`, so they end up like |a  b  c  d|. What would it mean to add e.g. `justify-self: center` or 'justify-self: flex-end` just to item 'b' there? Where would you expect it to go? (I see some demos in one of the answers here, but I don't see a clear way that it would work in general.)

Comment: (Alternately: suppose we have `justify-content: flex-start`, so the items are crowded at the beginning like |abcd   |.  What would you expect it to do, if you put `justify-self: [anything]` on item 'b' there?)

Comment: @dholbert, you wrote: *How would you expect `justify-self` to work for a flex item?* I would say not so differently than `auto` margins already work on flex items. In your second example, `justify-self: flex-end` on item d would move it to the far edge. That in itself would be a great feature, which `auto` margins can already do. I posted an answer with a demonstration.

Comment: I'm mostly seeing more use-cases here, and use-cases are great -- but the tricky bit is how to shoehorn this into the *actual* way that `justify-content` and `justify-self` are specified, so that cases with conflicts (like the scenarios I asked about) are clearly & sensibly defined.  As I noted in my answer here, `{justify|align}-self`are about aligning items *within a larger box which is sized independently of the `{justify|align}-self` value* -- and there is no such box, in the main axis, for a flex item to be aligned into.

Comment: RE "no different from auto margins" - I was actually asking about how you imagine `justify-self` and `justify-content` would interact, in cases where they conflict (like the scenarios I laid out).  Auto margins simply do *not* interact with `justify-content` at all - they steal all of the packing space before `justify-content` gets a chance to use it. So, auto margins aren't really a good analog for how this would work.

Comment: Because that would be _consistent_ and would break with the long CSS tradition of  _inconsistency_.

Answer (score 1915, accepted):

### Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis

As stated in the question:

> To align flex items along the main axis there is one property: [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)
>
> To align flex items along the cross axis there are three properties: [`align-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property), [`align-items` and `align-self`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property).

The question then asks:

> Why are there no `justify-items` and `justify-self` properties?

One answer may be: *Because they're not necessary.*

The [flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) provides *two* methods for aligning flex items along the main axis:

1. The `justify-content` keyword property, and
2. [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

---

### justify-content

The [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) property aligns flex items along the main axis of the flex container.

It is applied to the flex container but only affects flex items.

There are five alignment options:

- **`flex-start`** ~ Flex items are packed toward the start of the line.

  [image]
- **`flex-end`** ~ Flex items are packed toward the end of the line.

  [image]
- **`center`** ~ Flex items are packed toward the center of the line.

  [image]
- **`space-between`** ~ Flex items are evenly spaced, with the first item aligned to one edge of the container and the last item aligned to the opposite edge. The edges used by the first and last items depends on [`flex-direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property) and [writing mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) (`ltr` or `rtl`).

  [image]
- **`space-around`** ~ Same as `space-between` except with half-size spaces on both ends.

  [image]

---

### Auto Margins

With [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins), flex items can be centered, spaced away or packed into sub-groups.

Unlike `justify-content`, which is applied to the flex container, `auto` margins go on flex items.

They work by consuming all free space in the specified direction.

---

#### Align group of flex items to the right, but first item to the left

Scenario from the question:

> - making a group of flex items align-right (`justify-content: flex-end`)
>     but have the first item align left (`justify-self: flex-start`)
>
>   *Consider a header section with a group of nav items and a logo. With
>     `justify-self` the logo could be aligned left while the nav items stay
>     far right, and the whole thing adjusts smoothly ("flexes") to
>     different screen sizes.*

[image]

[image]

---

***Other useful scenarios:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

#### Place a flex item in the corner

Scenario from the question:

> - placing a flex item in a corner `.box { align-self: flex-end; justify-self: flex-end; }`

[image]

---

#### Center a flex item vertically and horizontally

[image]

`margin: auto` is an alternative to `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`.

Instead of this code on the flex container:

```
.container {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

You can use this on the flex item:

```
.box56 {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This alternative is useful when [**centering a flex item that overflows the container**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276).

---

#### Center a flex item, and center a second flex item between the first and the edge

A flex container aligns flex items by distributing free space.

Hence, in order to create *equal balance*, so that a middle item can be centered in the container with a single item alongside, a counterbalance must be introduced.

In the examples below, invisible third flex items (boxes 61 & 68) are introduced to balance out the "real" items (box 63 & 66).

[image]

[image]

Of course, this method is nothing great in terms of semantics.

Alternatively, you can use a pseudo-element instead of an actual DOM element. Or you can use absolute positioning. All three methods are covered here: **[Center and bottom-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276)**

*NOTE: The examples above will only work – in terms of true centering – when the outermost items are equal height/width. When flex items are different lengths, see next example.*

---

#### Center a flex item when adjacent items vary in size

Scenario from the question:

> - in a row of three flex items, affix the middle item to the center of the container  (`justify-content: center`) and align the adjacent
>     items to the container edges (`justify-self: flex-start` and
>     `justify-self: flex-end`).
>
>   *Note that values `space-around` and `space-between` on `justify-content` property  will not keep the middle item centered in relation to the container if the adjacent items have different widths ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7an37m20/12/)).*

As noted, unless all flex items are of equal width or height (depending on `flex-direction`), the middle item cannot be truly centered. This problem makes a strong case for a `justify-self` property (designed to handle the task, of course).

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: springgreen;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.box3 {
  width: 200px;
}
#center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#center > span {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <span>TRUE CENTER</span>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>

<p>The middle box will be truly centered only if adjacent boxes are equal width.</p>
```

*Here are two methods for solving this problem:*

***Solution #1: Absolute Positioning***

The flexbox spec allows for [absolute positioning of flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). This allows for the middle item to be perfectly centered regardless of the size of its siblings.

Just keep in mind that, like all absolutely positioned elements, the items are removed from the [document flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow). This means they don't take up space in the container and can overlap their siblings.

In the examples below, the middle item is centered with absolute positioning and the outer items remain in-flow. But the same layout can be achieved in reverse fashion: Center the middle item with `justify-content: center` and absolutely position the outer items.

[image]

***Solution #2: Nested Flex Containers (no absolute positioning)***

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box71 > span { margin-right: auto; }
.box73 > span { margin-left: auto;  }

/* non-essential */
.box {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box71"><span>71 short</span></div>
  <div class="box box72"><span>72 centered</span></div>
  <div class="box box73"><span>73 loooooooooooooooong</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's how it works:

- The top-level div (`.container`) is a flex container.
- Each child div (`.box`) is now a flex item.
- Each `.box` item is given `flex: 1` in order to distribute container space equally.
- Now the items are consuming all space in the row and are equal width.
- Make each item a (nested) flex container and add `justify-content: center`.
- Now each `span` element is a centered flex item.
- Use flex `auto` margins to shift the outer `span`s left and right.

You could also forgo `justify-content` and use `auto` margins exclusively.

But `justify-content` can work here because `auto` margins always have priority. From the spec:

> [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

---

#### justify-content: space-same (concept)

Going back to [`justify-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) for a minute, here's an idea for one more option.

- **`space-same`** ~ A hybrid of `space-between` and `space-around`. Flex items are evenly spaced (like `space-between`), except instead of half-size spaces on both ends (like `space-around`), there are full-size spaces on both ends.

This layout can be achieved with [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) pseudo-elements on the flex container.

[image]

*<sup>(credit: [@oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455480/3597276) for the code, and [@crl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3183756/crl) for the label)</sup>*

**UPDATE:** Browsers have begun implementing **`space-evenly`**, which accomplishes the above. See this post for details: [Equal space between flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45134400/3597276)

---

[**PLAYGROUND**](http://jsfiddle.net/mz1ft6jx/8/) (includes code for all examples above)

Comment: The answer above covers the *main-axis*, `justify-content` and `auto` margins. For the other side of the coin -- the *cross-axis*, `align-items`, `align-self` and `align-content` -- see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276

Comment: Good examples, but the centering aspect is still non-trivial. How would you adjust **Solution #2: Nested Flex Containers** when there is an uneven number of items surrounding the middle item? See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/7u6woja0/), where the container approach leads to the center item being slightly misaligned from absolute center if we have two items to the right. As you note, the absolute positioning has the disadvantage that it is removed from the document flow, which is not ideal either.

Comment: @MarkW, you're making the case for the `justify-self` property... `auto` margins are helpful, but `justify-self: center` would be ideal. The way to solve the problem you presented would be to create invisible duplicate items on the opposite side. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276

Comment: Your `space-same` concept is a real thing now. It's called `space-evenly`, but it's only supported by Firefox at the moment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: @benface, Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I've actually been writing about `space-evenly` in other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45134400/3597276

Comment: In fact, `space-evenly` _was_ supported in Chrome 57-60, but only for Grid layout. It was a bug that has been fixed, and since Chrome 61 it is supported there for Flexbox as well. Also, there is the way to emulate it without pseudo-elements: `.item { margin-right: auto } .item:first-child { margin-left: auto }`.

Comment: Soon time for an update :) ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: @LGSon, on that MDN page, click on the link to the spec. You'll find that justify-self does not (and will not) apply to flex items. They even have a section covering this issue: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#justify-flex

Comment: Interesting, as on the MDN page, in the Syntax/Value section, the value `flex-start` explicit states _...the alignment container depending on the **flex container's** main-start or cross-start side_

Comment: @LGSon, yes, I saw that. As good as MDN is, it's still second-hand information (and, as you can see, subject to human error). It's always safer to refer to the original source: The W3C. Browser makers don't refer to MDN. They use the specs.

Comment: Should any and all flex-box questions be closed as duplicates to this?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425681/flexbox-make-two-divs-on-left-and-third-on-right/48425753#48425753) was closed as a duplicate.  Clearly, this post covers it all.  Just wondering if we should be closing flex questions with a general "here's everything you need to know", rather than answering specific questions with "here's where you went wrong".

Comment: @MatthewJohnson, in reference to your linked question, this answer is not a "general" solution. In fact, it gives a specific solution to the problem described, and an explanation. But if you don't agree, you can vote to reopen.

Comment: I really hope the people at CSS Consortium (or how they call themselves) will take the idea of justify-self into regard... I sometimes find it ridiculous how complicated workarounds you sometimes have to do to achieve problem solutions... as if anybody really knows about those "tricks" that you mentioned above ;)

Comment: If it helps anyone, `margin: auto` isn't _just_ an alternative to `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`. If the item extends past the parent boundaries, the parent's overflow will allow the full item to be viewed with scrollbars with `auto`. This isn't the case when it's centered by flex, it goes off the edges and the scrollbar does nothing.

Comment: What if I need to set block alignment along main axis with styles of that block, while it's parent has justify-content set? Is it possible?

Comment: I think there is still one use-case that would be perfect for `justify-self` – it's when you want item to be stretched as soon as it's wrapped, in that case you could write `justify-self: stretch`, currently it's not possible with justify-content and auto margins

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin you said because it's not needed for main axis, but it is not needed for cross axis as well, right? you can use the same technics

Answer (score 236):

I know this is not an answer, but I'd like to contribute to this matter for what it's worth. It would be great if they could release `justify-self` for flexbox to make it truly flexible.

It's my belief that when there are multiple items on the axis, the most logical way for `justify-self` to behave is to align itself to its nearest neighbours (or edge) as demonstrated below.

I truly hope, W3C takes notice of this and will at least consider it. =)

[image]

This way you can have an item that is truly centered regardless of the size of the left and right box. When one of the boxes reaches the point of the center box it will simply push it until there is no more space to distribute.

[image]

The ease of making awesome layouts are endless, take a look at this "complex" example.

[image]

Comment: @Mark this is amazing! Thank you for taking the time to draft this. I hope you don’t mind but I’ve submitted it here: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/flexbox-justify-self-property/1146

Comment: Hi Mark, @Zaqx, I posted an answer that may cover some of the use-cases mentioned in this answer. I've discovered that a lot can still be done in the main axis without needing `justify-self` and `justify-items`.

Comment: Regarding centering something in between two other items I recently had to do the same and came up with using css grid and `grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, 1fr) 1200px minmax(100px, 1fr)` for centering something inside fixed margins. As the page expands the 1st and 3rd column end up the same size (once the page width is greater than 1200+50+100) which means the 2nd column is dead center. I used this for 'springy' margins but the 1st and 3rd column could equally contain actual content and then you'd probably use `min-content`.

Answer (score 32):

This was asked on the www-style list, and Tab Atkins (spec editor) [provided an answer explaining why](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Apr/0114.html). I'll elaborate on that a bit here.

To start out, let's initially assume our flex container is single-line (`flex-wrap: nowrap`). In this case, there's clearly an alignment difference between the main axis and the cross axis -- there are multiple items stacked in the main axis, but only one item stacked in the cross axis. So it makes sense to have a customizeable-per-item "align-self" in the cross axis (since each item is aligned separately, on its own), whereas it doesn't make sense in the main axis (since there, the items are aligned collectively).

For multi-line flexbox, the same logic applies to each "flex line". In a given line, items are aligned individually in the cross axis (since there's only one item per line, in the cross axis), vs. collectively in the main axis.

---

Here's another way of phrasing it: so, *all* of the `*-self` and `*-content` properties are about how to distribute extra space around things.  But the key difference is that the `*-self` versions are for cases where there's *only a single thing in that axis*, and the `*-content` versions are for when there are potentially *many things in that axis*. The one-thing vs. many-things scenarios are different types of problems, and so they have different types of options available -- for example, the `space-around` / `space-between` values make sense for `*-content`, but not for `*-self`.

SO: In a flexbox's main axis, there are many things to distribute space around. So a `*-content` property makes sense there, but not a `*-self` property.

In contrast, in the cross axis, we have both a `*-self` and a `*-content` property.  One determines how we'll distribute space around the *many* flex lines (`align-content`), whereas the other (`align-self`) determines how to distribute space around *individual* flex items in the cross axis, within a given flex line.

(I'm ignoring `*-items` properties here, since they simply establish defaults for `*-self`.)

Comment: I understand how a `justify-self` could be a problem on an axis with multiple items as opposed to one item. However I really hope they will look into it further, in a multiple items situation how would `justify-self` behave, because there are some situations where this could be really useful. For example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378953/how-can-you-keep-the-center-box-centered-in-a-flex-box-layout).

Comment: Nice find on that mailing list. Trying to wrap my head around it, as I still see good use case possibilities for `justify-self`.

Comment: I added a bit more clarification, explaining how `*-self` is about cases where we only have *one* thing to align whereas `*-content` is about cases where we have *many* things to align. Does that make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Yes, it's more clear. I appreciate the explanation. But it seems to all boil down to a simple preference by the spec authors, not a particular need based on logic. From the [mailing list you referenced](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Apr/0114.html): *The *-self properties only work if the child is all alone in that axis.* Why? There doesn't seem to be a need for this. It's an arbitrary decision. A preference. In fact, `auto` margins, also part of the spec, enable *-self alignment with multiple items in the line. No clear reason why keyword properties can't, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't use flexbox, but for the simple use-case of three items (one at left, one at center, one at right), this can be accomplished easily using `display: grid` on the parent, `grid-area: 1/1/1/1;` on the children, and `justify-self` for positioning of those children.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; display: grid; width: 100px; height: 25px;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 25px; grid-area: 1/1/1/1; justify-self: left;"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 25px; grid-area: 1/1/1/1; justify-self: center;"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 25px; grid-area: 1/1/1/1; justify-self: right;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really address the question. Also, there's a simpler way to accomplish your layout: https://jsfiddle.net/fga89m2o/

Answer (score 1):

I just found my own solution to this problem, or at least my problem.
I was using `justify-content: space-around` instead of `justify-content: space-between;`.

This way the end elements will stick to the top and bottom, and you could have custom margins if you wanted.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please only provide answers that directly address the question asked by the OP.